# Material Button Toggle Group single selection

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button

How can I force a **MaterialButtonToggleGroup** to act like a RadioGroup as in having at least one selected item always? Setting `setSingleSelection(true)` also adds the possibility to have nothing selected if you click twice on a Button in the group.

Here is my code:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
            android:id="@id/BottomSheetDialog_fromFragmentBottomSheetSort_Sort_ToggleButtonGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:singleSelection="true"
            app:checkedButton="@+id/BottomSheetDialog_fromFragmentBottomSheetSort_Sort_ToggleButtonGroup_Ascending">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@id/BottomSheetDialog_fromFragmentBottomSheetSort_Sort_ToggleButtonGroup_Ascending"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Fragment_BottomSheetDialog_Sort_ToggleButton_Ascending"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/custom_button_background_states"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@id/BottomSheetDialog_fromFragmentBottomSheetSort_Sort_ToggleButtonGroup_Descending"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Fragment_BottomSheetDialog_Sort_ToggleButton_Descending"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/custom_button_background_states"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"/>
    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

As you can see, even while using **app:singleSelection="true"** if i click on an already checked button, it unchecks it leaving no button checked in the group.

Comment: Have u tried with `app:singleSelection="true"` because for me it's working fine

Comment: I said above that i am using app:singleSelection="true" and when i click on the button twice, it **unchecks** the button.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## UPDATE :

#### `app:selectionRequired="true"` attribute is available as of version 1.2.0

Override the `toggle()` method of the `MaterialButton` class and use it instead of `MaterialButton`

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton

class CustomMaterialToggleButton : MaterialButton {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    override fun toggle() {
        if (!isChecked) {
            super.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

This will make sure that already checked button is not unchecked on single selection.

Answer (score 18):

As of [1.2.0-alpha03](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/a4b90321e32e1dbc0414958bea14a28f9fe68e14) you can simply use the `selectionRequired` option:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    android:id="@+id/toggle_button_group"
    app:singleSelection="true"
    app:selectionRequired="true">

</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

Answer (score 9):

Now you can achieve it using the **`app:selectionRequired`** attribute.
Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        app:singleSelection="true"
        app:selectionRequired="true"
        app:checkedButton="@id/..."
        ..>
```

Also you can programmatically use the method **`setSelectionRequired`**:

```
buttonGroup.setSelectionRequired(true);
```

Please note that this attribute **requires** a minimum of version **1.2.0-alpha03**

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to do this, you can go about it this way in Kotlin.

```
toggle_group.forEach { button ->
      button.setOnClickListener { (button as MaterialButton).isChecked = true }
}
```

This will prevent second click unchecking.