# How to make material toggle button in Android to behave like Switch?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button, material-components, material-components-android

I am using the following material design library

`implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha01"`

And this is how I am implementing my Material Toggle Button

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    id="@+id/toggleBtnGroup"
    app:singleSelection="true"
    android:id="@+id/toggle_button_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:checkedButton="@+id/leftAlign">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        id="@+id/leftAlign"
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left"/>
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        id="@+id/centerAlign"
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Center"/>
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        id="@+id/rightAlign"
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Right"/>

</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

Now, as I select other buttons, only 1 button is selected at a time, how can I make sure that if user selects the selected button again, it does not gets unselected. So in essence, I want atleast one of these buttons to be selected at a particular time. [image: Material Button Toggle]

How would one do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement this, do something like this :-

```
//We are adding a button checked listener to the toggle group
toggleBtnGroup.addOnButtonCheckedListener { group, checkedId, isChecked ->
    if (isChecked){
        //Do something
    } else {
        //Something is unchecked, we need to make sure that all the buttons are not un-selected
        if(-1 == group.checkedButtonId){
            //All buttons are unselected
            //So now we will select the button which was unselected right now
            group.check(checkedId)
        }
    }
}
```

Basically we are checking if isChecked is false, then checking if all the buttons are unselected, if so, we will then select the button, which was recently unselected.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the **`app:selectionRequired`** attribute.
Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        app:singleSelection="true"
        app:selectionRequired="true"
        app:checkedButton="@id/..."
        ..>
```

You can also use the method **`setSelectionRequired`**:

```
buttonGroup.setSelectionRequired(true);
```

This attribute **requires** a minimum of version **1.2.0-alpha03**

Comment: Your answers are saving me so much time! x3 in a row

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I faced the same problem as when I click on the button twice, it unchecks the button. I solved this issue by Override `toggle()` method of the `MaterialButton` class from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57090690/material-button-toggle-group-single-selection).

Comment: Hi, just wanted to say, it is now a part of Material Design Library, we don't need to write our own code for it. It is available in the alpha version, right now